# Самопроизвольная установка Firefox

Tags: администрирование, firefox

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема: примерно раз в 2-3 дня на комп устанавливается Mozilla Firefox. Без возможности удаления. Удаляется только если скачать и установить Firefox поверх уже установленного. На вирусы комп проверен Dr. Web CureIt и через систему, и с LiveUSB. Найденные вирусы все удалил, но Firefox так же устанавливается сам по себе. Может кто сталкивался, подскажете в каком направлении рыть вообще? Или, может, какое-то решение уже есть, но я не нашел. Система: windows 8.

Comment: То есть вирусы всё же были?

Comment: Может, там стоит какая-нибудь утилита удалённого управления?

Comment: @VLADD точно могу сказать что TeamViewer стоит. Ярлык Firefox'а появляется только после загрузки из выключенного состояния, пока компом пользуешься его нет. Какой то последовательности действий после которых Firefox появляется пока не обнаружил, единственное что это всегда примерно 2-3 дня. Вирусы - да, были. 60 штук. К сожалению лог не сохранился :(

Comment: @VladD вирусы были, удалены одноразовой утилитой CleanIt, значит, антивирусной защиты онлайн на компе не установлено, какие действия в 2-3 дня производятся - непонятно. Вопрос надо закрывать, как неповторяемый.

Comment: Если там было найдено 60 (!) вирусов, то с хорошими шансами ещё парочку осталось. Вы бы посмотрели, что запускается при старте. Например, при помощи этого: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: @vladd спасибо, попробую